# ajax call on maxLength - not updating on CTRL V (paste)

Tags: jquery, ajax, input, maxlength

```
//show city/state on input maxlength
$("input#billZipCode").live("keyup", function( event ){

    if(this.value.length == this.getAttribute('maxlength')) {
        if(!$(this).data('triggered')) {
            // set the 'triggered' data attribute to true
            $(this).data('triggered', true); 
            if ($(this).valid() == true ) { zipLookup(this, "USA"); } 
        }
    } else {
    $(this).data('triggered', false);
    }

});
```

the function `zipLookup` performs an ajax call and populates the fields.

The above works for when a user keys in zipcodes - however, if a user puts in a zipcode and then pastes (CTRL V) a new zipcode value, the function doesn't fire again.

Comment: The easiest way around this would be to require the user to click a button or press the return key to invoke this - otherwise you'll have to write some custom code that detects pasting (both from keyboard and mouse) as well as typing.

Comment: @Utkanos - yes, I want to write custom code to do that - hence posting on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may catch the paste event :

```
$(document).on('change keyup paste', '#billZipCode', function(){
   // do something
});​​​​​​
```

Reference on the `onpaste` callback used by jquery : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onpaste

Note that, as specified in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/), this doesn't work on IE8 : you have to attach the `paste` event directly to the element :

> In Internet Explorer 8 and lower, the paste and reset events do not
>   bubble. Such events are not supported for use with delegation, but
>   they can be used when the event handler is directly attached to the
>   element generating the event.

Side notes :

- use "#billZipCode" and not "input#billZipCode"
- use `on`, not `live` (which is deprecated)

Comment: Unable to use `.on` with jQuery 1.6.2 - but I'm assuming the approach is the same

Comment: Yes, it's the same. But why don't you upgrade jQuery ?